# Can you detect a "settled" state from a service worker to trigger the caching of assets after the page content has loaded?

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker

I want to prioritise the first paint and TTI metrics before the service worker jumps in and prefetches assets.

Is there any reliable way to detect the a "settled" state of the page via JavaScript, either from within a service worker or from the page context itself?

For instance, can I add an event listener for a browser-evaluated metric like TTI?

Comment: Why does your ServiceWorker blocks the first paint to begin with? It should run in another process. Then yes, you can postMessage to your SW to let it know how it's going in the front side, but that sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Oh, the service-worker does not block anything, it's more that I want to ensure that absolutely nothing non essential is happening in the critical render path. If the SW spawns immediately and starts pre-fetching resources while the page is loading, it will compete for resources and negatively affect the user's experience.

Answer (score 0):

I can use a `PerformanceObserver` to detect the `first-contentful-paint`

```js
async function onFirstContentfulPaint() {
  const findFirstContentfulPaint = (performanceEntries) => {
    for (const { name } of performanceEntries) {
      if (name !== 'first-contentful-paint') continue
      return true
    }
  }

  if (findFirstContentfulPaint(window.performance.getEntries())) {
    return
  }

  return new Promise(res => {
    const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
      if (findFirstContentfulPaint(list.getEntries())) {
        observer.disconnect()
        res()
      }
    })
    observer.observe({ type: "paint", buffered: true });
  }) 
}

// wait for first paint then run your code
onFirstContentfulPaint().then(main)
```